# Ember Data using wrong request method when a Computed Property added

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a detailed observation for this. Not sure what I am doing wrong here. I have a model definition where I compute a boolean value. Which causing the `deleteRecord()` method to send data with a wrong request method (`POST` instead of `DELETE`). Also when I call `save()` method it sends the request through `PUT` instead of `POST`

**Please note:** Code works fine when I remove the computed property definition.

### The model definition

```
var attr = DS.attr(),
    string = DS.attr('string'),
    boolean = DS.attr('boolean'),
    number = DS.attr('number'),
    hasMany = DS.hasMany();

App.Status = DS.Model.extend({
    sticky: boolean,
    title: string,
    date: string,
    categories: attr,
    content: string,
    comment_allowed: boolean,
    replying: DS.attr('boolean', {defaultValue: false}),

    isNew: function(){ 
        var unix = parseInt( moment(this.get('date')).format('X') );
        var current = parseInt(moment().format('X'));
        var four_hours = 60 * 60 * 4;
        return ( (unix + four_hours) > current);
    }.property('date')

});
```

### Deleting an Item From Controller

When I try to delete the record form an action handler `destroyRecord()` make ajax request with `POST` instead of `DELETE`. Also the request url is wrong. It gets sends to `/statuses` instead of `/status/id`

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {

        deleteStatus: function(status_id){

            if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this status?'))
                return;

            this.store.find('status', status_id).then(function(status){
                console.log(status);
                status.destroyRecord();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Also note that the computed property function working as expected without any errors.

### Edit

Find the code for `RESTAdapter` below. Again if I comment out the Computed Property part the code works fine.

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: config.siteUrl,
    namespace: 'wp-json',
    headers: {
        "X-WP-Nonce": config.nonce
    }
});
```

Comment: did you extend your DS.RESTAdapter somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `isNew` for a property name, as ember-data is already using that for its own purposes.  Try changing the property to `isRecent` or something similar.

Comment: That was it! Didn't knew `isNew` is reserved!! Thank you!